# PHP script giving null output from phpbb SQL DB

Tags: php, html, sql, phpbb3

first of all: I'm a complete newbie if it comes to PHP scripting, so I just grabbed this script off a website, with the author saying it worked perfectly.

```
 <?php
// How Many Topics you want to display?
$topicnumber = 5;
// Scrolling towards up or down?
$scroll = "up";
// Change this to your phpBB path
$urlPath = "/forum";

// Database Configuration (Where your phpBB config.php file is located)
include 'forum/config.php';

$table_topics = $table_prefix. "topics";
$table_forums = $table_prefix. "forums";
$table_posts = $table_prefix. "posts";
$table_users = $table_prefix. "users";
$link = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpasswd") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die("Could not select database");

$query = "SELECT t.topic_id, t.topic_title, t.topic_last_post_id, t.forum_id,
p.post_id, p.poster_id, p.post_time, u.user_id, u.username
FROM $table_topics t, $table_forums f, $table_posts p, $table_users u WHERE t.topic_id = p.topic_id AND f.forum_id = t.forum_id AND t.topic_status = 2 AND p.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id AND p.poster_id = u.user_id ORDER BY p.post_id DESC LIMIT $topicnumber";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed");

echo "
";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "
";
}
print "

" .
$row["topic_title"] .
"    by: " .
$row["username"] .
"   
" .
date('F j, Y, g:i a', $row["post_time"]) .
"
";
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Although when I use it, it gives me a weird as heck output being "by: December 31, 1969, 7:00 pm". Instead of (the only topic it should find now) "Test1 by: Cruciatum July 8th, 2012, 10pm".

Anyone who can figure out what's wrong in this? (It's used through an iframe on the right of this page: [Website](http://bpro.cu.cc))

PS: It's supposed to get the topic name, author, date & time of the last 5 posts in my phpbb3 forum.

PPS: Here's the iframe code

```
<!-- Recent posts -->
<div class="divx" style="position:absolute; top:170px; right:10px; width:200px; height:300px;">
<iframe height="300px" width="200px" scrolling="no" src="fetch.php">
</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Most likely, the database query succeeds, but finds no rows. Then when it attempts to write output, all variables are empty and the `date()` call gets a null input value, hence returning the zero-value timestamp, which happens to be Dec 31 1969 19:00 in your timezone.

Comment: using a random script you don't understand is dangerous.

Comment: @Dagon, I know, although I do understand - mostly - what it does, I'm used to programming, just not in PHP/SQL :>

Comment: @Michael Well, the DB should have (at least) 1 record that should give the query a value, since I have (atm) 1 topic in there which should pop up.

Comment: @Yorrick it filters out forum_id=4. If your post is in that forum, it won't return.

Comment: @Michael There's only 1 forum on at the moment, so if that forum has forum_id 4, that would be weird & really unlucky I'ld say. I'll try pulling out that filter.

As I thought, nothing changed. :(

Comment: I'm guessing one of the tables topics, forums, posts or users does not have a row in it - if any of these tables does not have a row relating to the corresponding topic then no rows will come back

Comment: @soupy1976 What would be a fix for it if that's indeed the case?
I'm about to get some other people to register & create topics to check if it's that screwing with the code.

Comment: You'd need to either (i) work out why a row isn't going into that table, or (ii) rewrite the SQL (probably using a LEFT OUTER JOIN) to bring back a result even in the absence of a row in whichever table it is

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that in the WHERE caluse you have: 't.topic_status 2' - this should surely be 't.topic_status = 2' ?

Comment: Allready fixed that after posting & still giving me the wrong output.

Comment: @soupy1976 I remember now, that thing made my query fail, didn't cause the wrong output.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13589/discussion-between-yorrick-and-soupy1976)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it:

```
<?php
// How Many Topics you want to display?
$topicnumber = 5;
// Scrolling towards up or down?
$scroll = "up";
// Change this to your phpBB path
$urlPath = "/forum";

// Database Configuration (Where your phpBB config.php file is located)
include 'forum/config.php';

$table_topics = $table_prefix. "topics";
$table_forums = $table_prefix. "forums";
$table_posts = $table_prefix. "posts";
$table_users = $table_prefix. "users";
$link = mysql_connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpasswd") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("$dbname") or die("Could not select database");

$query = "SELECT t.topic_id, t.topic_title, t.topic_last_post_id, t.forum_id,
p.post_id, p.poster_id, p.post_time, u.user_id, u.username
FROM $table_topics as t, $table_forums as f, $table_posts as p, $table_users as u WHERE t.topic_id = p.topic_id AND f.forum_id = t.forum_id AND t.topic_status != 2 AND p.post_id = t.topic_last_post_id AND t.topic_last_poster_id = u.user_id ORDER BY p.post_id DESC LIMIT $topicnumber";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed");

echo "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "";

print "<a href=\"forum/viewtopic.php?f=" .$row["forum_id"] ."&t=" .$row["topic_id"] ."\"><font color=\"darkred\">" .$row["topic_title"] ."</font></a>       by: <a href=\"forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=" .$row["user_id"] ."\"><font color=\"darkred\">" .$row["username"] ."</font></a> 
" .date('F j, Y, g:i a', $row["post_time"]) ."<br/><br/>";
}

mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Added links & stuff aswell while I was at it :>

Answer (score 0):

Typical PHP script and typical PHP problems - no checking of anything.

- check for error codes
- check the number of returned rows
- check the SQL being sent to the tables
- run the SQL manually and check the result

I'm sure you'll figure out then.

Comment: Did most of that, but as I said, I'm still a newbie in relation to PHP/SQL

Comment: PS: Returned rows = 0
Now, instead of being arrogant, maybe help a person out? Which is kind of the whole idea behind this site?